# Programmatic custom UITableViewCell with autolayout wrong contentView width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm creating a settings page with a grouped UITableView. Some cells only contain a button and I created a custom UITableViewCell which would be reused whenever I need that (several places already).

What I'm facing is that whenever I set a text to the cell's button's title, button size doesn't change so it doesn't show the text or position correctly within the cell (as it would do if I had made the view in IB).

This is my custom cell

```
#import "XRPButtonTableViewCell.h"
#import "XRPBaseTableViewCellProtected.h"

@interface XRPButtonTableViewCell ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
@end

@implementation XRPButtonTableViewCell

- (void) setupCell {
    [super setupCell];

    NSDictionary *views = @{@"button": self.button};
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                    constant:0.0]];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[button]-|"
                                    options:0
                                    metrics:nil
                                    views:views]];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(>=8)-[button]-(>=8)-|"
                                    options:0
                                    metrics:nil
                                    views:views]];

    [self.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- (UIButton *) button {
    if (!_button) {
       _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       _button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
       _button.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

       [self.contentView addSubview:_button];
    }

    return _button;
}

@end
```

In the UITableView class I've already set `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to the `rowHeight` and also registered the CustomTableViewCell class.

And this is how I use it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
case XRPSettingsButton: {

    XRPButtonTableViewCell *cell = (XRPButtonTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[XRPButtonTableViewCell cellReuseIdentifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.button setTitle:@"Press button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}
```

What am I missing?

Update: I've noticed that the cell's contentView has a width of zero. I'm failing to understand the reason, since other custom cells (different type) have the correct width.

Problem seems to appear only when using iOS 10. If using iOS 8 or 9, the button does appear, but is tightly wrapped by the cell's contentView. What I don't get then is why contentView isn't set to the superview's width as with other custom cells I have and I use the same approach.

I've uploaded a [sample code](https://github.com/jrpinteno/Sample/tree/master/Sample). `XRPViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` which holds the UITableView and so.

Comment: instead of this self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints use button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints and check...there are more possible reasons but this is guess...if you post a sample project with this chunk of code i can try and fix with different options.  i can also guess this is the prpblem of auto layout and also it can be a problem of not using estimatedRowHeight

Comment: Forgot to say `estimatedRowHeight` was also set. And both self.contentView and button have the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to NO.


I've updated the question with a Sample project in github.

Comment: give me the sample project link. i will try every possibilities.

Comment: [Here it is](https://github.com/jrpinteno/Sample/tree/master/Sample), also in main question

Comment: sorry bro, i think its XCode 8 project and i don't have that. i heard its not stable for old project files so i did not downloaded it yet.

Comment: Ah, yes, it is. No worries, thanks for your time anyway :)